# why Jquery mobile table not working with different mobile phone?

Tags: html, layout, mobile, jquery-mobile

I want to create a 5-column table firstly using JQuery mobile table. Here is my code:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">検査項目</th>
      <th scope="col">半日ドック</th>
      <th scope="col">1泊ドック</th>
      <th scope="col">2泊ドック</th>
      <th scope="col">検診内容</th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>

  <tbody> 
    <tr>
      <th>診察</th>
      <td>○</td>
      <td>○</td>
      <td>○</td>
      <td>問診・聴打診</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my CSS is:

```css
table {
  width:100%;
  font-size:9px;
  background:#FAFBF5;
}

th {
  text-align:center;
  background:#C2E195;
  font-size:9px;
  border:1px solid;
}

td {
  text-align:center;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

One problem is, it soundly works in Sony Ericsson and other but don't works on iPhone.
Then I tried following code:

```html
<div class="ui-grid-d">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <div class="ui-bar-d" style="background:#C2E195; font-size:8px; color:#000000; text-align:center; height:50px">検査項目</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <div class="ui-bar-d" style="background:#ffffff; font-size:8px; color:#000000; text-align:center; height:50px">半日ドック</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <div class="ui-bar-d" style="background:#ffffff; font-size:8px; color:#000000; text-align:center; height:50px">1泊ドック</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-d">
    <div class="ui-bar-d" style="background:#ffffff; font-size:8px; color:#000000; text-align:center; height:50px">2泊ドック</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-e">
    <div class="ui-bar-d" style="background:#ffffff; font-size:8px; color:#000000; text-align:center; height:50px">検診内容</div>
  </div>
```

The problem is, that it works well in iPhone but *not* works in Sony Ericsson.

How can I make this work on both platforms?

Comment: Maybe the iPhone browser doesn't support the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags, try to format your table as [this w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp)

Comment: why not I use grid. Also I read a blog where it said table is not in best alternate. The main problem of using grid I failed to maintain height. Therefore large text specify more space than small. So i cannot use any ui-bar-a~d> While I use it table layout is broken..

Answer (score 0):

JQM doesn't have a table widget (yet). In the meantime, you can use my widget tableview ([example](http://www.franckreich.de/jqm/tableview/demo.html)/[Github](https://github.com/frequent/tableview)).

This gives you a basic JQM table layout with some responsive functions. Haven't really tested it in anything but iOS, Android 2.3 and desktop. Works nice, so give it a try.